# node.js, express, ejs Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am using paypal sdk and when I get the response from paypal with the details I am trying to send the transaction id back to my js for use. Here is what is in my .ejs

```
return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
    alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);

    return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/success/<%= data.userQuery %>/`, {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        orderID: details.id
      })
    });
```

And here is my js

```
app.post('/success/:userQuery/', (req, res) => {

console.log(req.body.orderID)});
```

I am getting undefined in my console log, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have too many question for your question, the first is How many time you call `res.send` or `res.json` or something like that in you express handler?

Comment: None of the code you show us causes the headers error by itself so you will have to show us more of your code before we can help.  Also, do you have `express.json()` middleware installed?  If not, that's why req.body is not filled with your post data.